# Stored procedure to Insert data between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to insert data from a table called `temp_menu` into another called `menu`.

They have the same structure, they store the same data, I want to create a stored procedure to check the differences between the tables. If there are any different rows and the rows don't exist in table `menu`, I want to insert them into `menu`; if the rows exists, I want to update the rows in `menu` if the `DateReg` column is higher that the `DateReg` column in the `temp_menu` table.

The tables have this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu_Temp]
(
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Ref] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Art] [char](60) NOT NULL,
    [Dish] [char](60) NOT NULL,
    [DateReg] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Zone] [char](60) NOT NULL,
);
```

I have this code to check for differences between the tables:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #diffs
FROM [Regi].dbo.menu
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM [Regi].dbo.menu_Temp

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN

SELECT * FROM #diffs
```

Comment: check out https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/using-the-merge-statement-to-perform-an-upsert.html

Comment: As per @Jeremy there is already a SQL command for doing `INSERT` and `UPDATE` together : `MERGE`.

Comment: Did you try searching at all? 'How can I insert or update' is an extremely popular SQL question that I doubt needs another duplicate answer.

Comment: The  problem  is how  to do the verifications to insert and update.

Comment: As already suggested you should use MERGE. Here is the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: Yes, I will look in to that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full details are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

An example for your situation could be...

```
MERGE
    [Regi].dbo.menu
USING
    [Regi].dbo.menu_Temp
        ON (menu_Temp.[Ref] = menu.[Ref])  -- Assumes [Ref] is the identifying column?
WHEN
    MATCHED AND (menu_Temp.[DateReg] > menu.[DateReg])
THEN
    UPDATE SET [Art]     = menu_Temp.[Art],
               [Dish]    = menu_Temp.[Dish],
               [Zone]    = menu_Temp.[Zone],
               [Date]    = menu_Temp.[Date],
               [DateReg] = menu_Temp.[DateReg]
WHEN
    NOT MATCHED
THEN  
    INSERT (
        [Date],
        [Ref],
        [Art],
        [Dish],
        [DateReg],
        [Zone]
    )
    VALUES (
        menu_Temp.[Date],
        menu_Temp.[Ref],
        menu_Temp.[Art],
        menu_Temp.[Dish],
        menu_Temp.[DateReg],
        menu_Temp.[Zone]
    )
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b47d7e879856ffe6210589f6bb64829f

Comment: Other site that I used:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37172/Merge-Statement-in-SQL-Server